# How to draw curves using function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graphics

I have written a code to draw a digit using Bezier curves, but I get an error: index 601 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 600. I am trying to draw digit "9" using 5 control points.

Here is a code:

```
import numpy as np               
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

img = np.ones((600,600,3))

def DrawBezier(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4):
    x = x0
    y = y0
    ts = 0.001
    t = 0
    while t <= 1.0:
    
        B0 = (1-t)**5
        B1 = 4 * t + 12 * t**3 - 12 * t**2
        B2 = 6 * t**4 - 12 * t**3 + 6 * t**2 
        B3 = 4 * t**3 - 4 * t**4
        B4 = t**4
        
        x = int(x0*B0 + x1*B1 + x2*B2 + x3*B3 + x4*B4)
        y = int(y0*B0 + y1*B1 + y2*B2 + y3*B3 + y4*B4)
        
        img[x,y] = (1,0,0)
        
        t=t+ts 
        
    return 


DrawBezier(270,480, 400,405 ,250,350 ,100,500, 500,500)
    
# %matplotlib notebook
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi = 100, facecolor='w')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of just `img[x,y] = (1,0,0)`, you could check whether you are inside the bounds. `if 0<=x<600 and 0<=y<600: img[x,y] = (1,0,0)`

Comment: You also might want to review your formulas, as they don't seem to make much sense. See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) which gives `B0 = (1-t)**4`, `B1 = 4*t*(1-t)**3` etc.

Comment: I have 5 control points, so I think formulas are correct

Comment: Well, your formulas are wrong. `B0 = (1-t)**5` would be OK for 6 control points. Your B1 is similar to the one for 5 points, but contains a typo. It misses `-4*t**4` or so.